# How to add Export and Email button in menu of Active Report 6.0?

Tags: c#-4.0, activereports

I have a viewer of Active Report 6.0.but in the toolbar menu Export and Email button when I export my report data to my local hard disk in pdf format no pdf is generated.

I have done some code in form lode and viewer_toolClick i.e

```
const long pdfExportToolID = 42;
        private void AR6ReportHostForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                DataDynamics.ActiveReports.Toolbar.Button myExportTool = default(DataDynamics.ActiveReports.Toolbar.Button);
                myExportTool = new DataDynamics.ActiveReports.Toolbar.Button();
                myExportTool.ButtonStyle = DataDynamics.ActiveReports.Toolbar.ButtonStyle.Text;
                myExportTool.Caption = "Export";
                myExportTool.Id = pdfExportToolID;
                this.viewer1.Toolbar.Tools.Add(myExportTool);
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

 private void viewer1_ToolClick(object sender, DataDynamics.ActiveReports.Toolbar.ToolClickEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if ((e.Tool.Id == pdfExportToolID))
                {
                    DataDynamics.ActiveReports.Export.Pdf.PdfExport pdf = new DataDynamics.ActiveReports.Export.Pdf.PdfExport();
                    pdf.Export(this.viewer1.Document, @"D:\\BlackCode");

                }
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

When I debug the code no pdf file is saved in given path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change file path

```
pdf.Export(this.viewer1.Document, @"D:\\BlackCode");
```

to

```
pdf.Export(this.viewer1.Document, Application.StartupPath + "\\PDFExpt.pdf");
```

the export pdf is saved in bin or debug folder in your application.

Comment: in your original code, the filename has to end in .pdf.  try D:\\BlackCode.pdf instead of D:\\BlackCode